# Query selector with body but not on id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I got stuck with the elements selecting whole body but not particular id in that body.
I tried the following things for the javascript

```
 var boxElemb =  document.querySelector("body:not('ul#id')");
    boxElemb.innerHTML=boxElemb.innerHTML.replace(/BOTÕES/g, 'Puxadores');
```

But it does not work. I am replacing the content with another text. Please help me out if any one has the solution

Comment: Do you need this selector to change the content of `ul#id`?  Or you want to change 'BOTÕES' with ''Puxadores' in the whole site excluding the ul#id ?

Comment: @brandt.codes yes you interpreted correctly I want to this on the complete body except the tab "#id" part

Comment: Given your selector, are you actually expecting to select the body tag, or something else? It might be clearer to post an excerpt of your html, and highlight what you want selected and what not.

Answer (score 2):

`ul#id` inside `not` is not a valid syntax.

Use `[id]`. Anything between `[` and `]` will be treated as attribute. You can also filter it using attribute value like `[id='myId']`.

```
document.querySelector("body:not('ul[id]')");
```

Comment: There would be no # while giving the id??

Comment: @HarshitSethi Yes, no `#` when it's inside of `:not(..)`

Comment: I'm not sure if the above query will fetch anything, because it means that you're trying to select `body` which is not `ul` with an `id` attribute.
But it is a valid query

Comment: This causes following error (index):4877 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'body:not('ul[tab1527316568708]')' is not a valid selector.

Comment: It does not works at all also specified through [id='myid']
(index):4877 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'body:not(ul[id='tab1527316568708'])' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Why do you need `ul` there? You probably want something like `body ul:not([id='tab1527316568708'])'` or `body:not([id='tab1527316568708'])'`

Comment: ul:not([id='tab1527316568708'])' or body:not([id='tab1527316568708'])' both of these doesnot works

Comment: Better if you could add the minimal HTML to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the `body`, and then remove the unnecessary `ul`. Like this:

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var ul = document.getElementById("your-id");
body.removeChild(ul);
```

That is in case your `ul` is the direct child of the `body` element, otherwise, you will need to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your Text in all the body, then in specific id replace it back

```
const body =  document.querySelector("body");
const id = document.querySelector("#id");
body.innerHTML=boxElemb.innerHTML.replace(/BOTÕES/g,'Puxadores');
id.innerHTML=boxElemb.innerHTML.replace('Puxadores', /BOTÕES/g);
```

Comment: I mean to apply elements on all body elements of DOM except the id elements. Could you please clarify more..

Comment: You can replace your Text in all the body, then in specific id replace it back

Comment: No I donot want to do that actually the tabbing does not work because of the replacement of text so I just want to left that part and to apply the text changes to other parts

Answer (score 0):

If you say the tabbing is not working if you change the text, then you are missing something else altogether. However, the below should work as per your requirement: **change everywhere except for ul with a specific id**

```
var body = document.querySelector('body'),
    ulIdText = document.querySelector('ul#id').innerHtml,
    bodyText = body.innerHTML
                 .replace(ulIdText,'_^_preallocatedtext_^_') 
                 .replace(/BOTÕES/g,'Puxadores')
                 .replace('_^_preallocatedtext_^_',ulIdText);

body.innerHTML = bodyText;
```

You can get rid of unnecessary variables here, but I advise to keep it this way so it is self-explanatory for revisiting later on.

The difference here compared to the other two answers

1. the entire HTML is fully formed before replacing the existing HTML.
2. `body:not` doesn't exclude the `not` part as `body` doesn't contain the exclusions in its tags/attributes. You'd need to use `document.querySelectorAll` but that'll require a huge loop.

Comment: The tabbing doesnot work due to rerendering of inner html as the translation works...

Comment: @HarshitSethi alright. Do checkout the above in case the other solutions don't work.